# Got "Timestamp conversion failed" when I tried to use "set_position()" to play a streaming video using python-vlc

Tags: python, vlc, python-vlc

I'M trying to add a playback function in streaming video

I got streaming video data from stream website and keep writing them in a .flv file. Then the video file will be played in python-vlc. When I tried to use `set_position()` to play the video in an exact time while the file still being writen, I met error like:

```
main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 100000, bound 9000000)
main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 1276954807000 for FFmpeg
```

and

```
main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed for 1027659001: no reference clock
main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 0 for FFmpeg
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: and where is your code? We can't read in your mind.